# Boostrap 5 - how to stack 6 cards in a row?

Tags: bootstrap-5

I was trying to make a 6 cards in the same row, but everytime I am adding the 4th and so on, this happens: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtbql.png)

Any idea how to solve this? I belive it's simple enough, below is my code.
Thanks in advance.

(It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.)

**Zakres usług**

```
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-6 mb-2">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="bg-image hover-overlay ripple" data-mdb-ripple-color="light">
              <img
                src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/new/standard/nature/023.jpg"
                class="img-fluid"
              />
              <a href="#!">
                <div class="mask" style="background-color: rgba(251, 251, 251, 0.15);"></div>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
              <p class="card-text">
                Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the
                card's content.
              </p>
              
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-6 mb-2">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="bg-image hover-overlay ripple" data-mdb-ripple-color="light">
              <img
                src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/new/standard/nature/023.jpg"
                class="img-fluid"
              />
              <a href="#!">
                <div class="mask" style="background-color: rgba(251, 251, 251, 0.15);"></div>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
              <p class="card-text">
                Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the
                card's content.
              </p>
              
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-6 mb-2">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="bg-image hover-overlay ripple" data-mdb-ripple-color="light">
              <img
                src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/new/standard/nature/111.jpg"
                class="img-fluid"
              />
              <a href="#!">
                <div class="mask" style="background-color: rgba(251, 251, 251, 0.15);"></div>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
              <p class="card-text">
                Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the
                card's content.
              </p>
               
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: what do you exactly want? because if i'm adding 4th it looks perfect in your code. for preview you can use below code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-6 mb-2">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="bg-image hover-overlay ripple" data-mdb-ripple-color="light">
                <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/new/standard/nature/023.jpg" class="img-fluid" />
                <a href="#!">
                    <div class="mask" style="background-color: rgba(251, 251, 251, 0.15);"></div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">
                    Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the
                    card's content.
                </p>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-6 mb-2">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="bg-image hover-overlay ripple" data-mdb-ripple-color="light">
                <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/new/standard/nature/023.jpg" class="img-fluid" />
                <a href="#!">
                    <div class="mask" style="background-color: rgba(251, 251, 251, 0.15);"></div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">
                    Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the
                    card's content.
                </p>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-6 mb-2">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="bg-image hover-overlay ripple" data-mdb-ripple-color="light">
                <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/new/standard/nature/111.jpg" class="img-fluid" />
                <a href="#!">
                    <div class="mask" style="background-color: rgba(251, 251, 251, 0.15);"></div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">
                    Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the
                    card's content.
                </p>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-6 mb-2">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="bg-image hover-overlay ripple" data-mdb-ripple-color="light">
                <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/new/standard/nature/023.jpg" class="img-fluid" />
                <a href="#!">
                    <div class="mask" style="background-color: rgba(251, 251, 251, 0.15);"></div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">
                    Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the
                    card's content.
                </p>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-6 mb-2">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="bg-image hover-overlay ripple" data-mdb-ripple-color="light">
                <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/new/standard/nature/023.jpg" class="img-fluid" />
                <a href="#!">
                    <div class="mask" style="background-color: rgba(251, 251, 251, 0.15);"></div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">
                    Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the
                    card's content.
                </p>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-6 mb-2">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="bg-image hover-overlay ripple" data-mdb-ripple-color="light">
                <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/new/standard/nature/111.jpg" class="img-fluid" />
                <a href="#!">
                    <div class="mask" style="background-color: rgba(251, 251, 251, 0.15);"></div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">
                    Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the
                    card's content.
                </p>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow thank you so much for help, you're my hero today:)

Answer (score -1):

```
<section>
    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="text-center">Skills</h1>
        <div class="row pt-3">
            
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-6 mb-2">
                <div class="card text-center p-3">
                    <i class="fa-brands fa-python display-1 text-info"></i>
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h5 class="card-title">Python</h5>
                      <p class="card-text"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-6 mb-2">
                <div class="card text-center p-3 display-1">
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-c"></i>
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h5 class="card-title">C </h5>
                      <p class="card-text"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-6 mb-2">
                <div class="card text-center p-3">
                    <i class="fa-brands fa-java display-1 text-primary"></i>
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h5 class="card-title">Java</h5>
                      <p class="card-text"></p>
                    
                    </div>
                </div>    
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-6 mb-2">
                <div class="card text-center p-3">
                    <i class="fa-brands fa-html5 display-1 text-danger"></i>
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h5 class="card-title">HTML5</h5>
                      <p class="card-text"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-6 mb-2">
                <div class="card text-center p-3">
                    <i class="fa-brands fa-css3-alt display-1 text-primary"></i>
                    <div class="card-body">
                       <h5 class="card-title">CSS3</h5>
                       <p class="card-text"></p>
                    
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-6 mb-2">
                <div class="card text-center p-3">
                    <i class="fa-brands fa-js display-1 text-warning"></i>
                    <div class="card-body">
                       <h5 class="card-title">JS</h5>
                       <p class="card-text"></p>
                    
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
                <div class="row pt-4">
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-6 mb-2">
                <div class="card text-center p-3">
                    <i class="fa-brands fa-bootstrap display-1 text-primary"</i>
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h5 class="card-title">Bootstrap</h5>
                      <p class="card-text"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-6 mb-2">
                <div class="card text-center p-3">
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-database display-1 text-warning"></i>
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h5 class="card-title">MySQL</h5>
                      <p class="card-text"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-6 mb-2">
                <div class="card text-center p-3">
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-code display-1 text-primary"></i>
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h5 class="card-title">PSQL</h5>
                      <p class="card-text"></p>
                    
                    </div>
                </div>    
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-6 mb-2">
                <div class="card text-center p-3">
                    <i class="fa-brands fa-react text-primary display-1"></i>
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h5 class="card-title">React</h5>
                      <p class="card-text"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-6 mb-2">
                <div class="card text-center p-3">
                    <i class="fa-brands fa-python display-1 text-info"></i>
                    <div class="card-body">
                       <h5 class="card-title">Django</h5>
                       <p class="card-text"></p>
                    
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-6 mb-2">
                <div class="card text-center p-3">
                    <i class="fa-brands fa-python display-1 text-info"></i>
                    <div class="card-body">
                       <h5 class="card-title">Flask</h5>
                       <p class="card-text"></p>
                    
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>    
</section>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).